# Sending an ajax post to a custom controller through carrier wave value change

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails, ajax, carrierwave, simple-form

I'm trying to send out an ajax post to my controller under a custom module. I'm using Carrierwave for the file uploader, devise to keep track of my users, and simple_form for my form control. When the user selects a file to upload, then I need the form to submit a post through coffescript to the controller so that I can handle it with an ajax function. My problem seems to be that I can't get the post to get through correctly to the controller, or get a response from the server at all.

Here is a snippet of the form I'm trying to submit

```
<%= simple_form_for @applicant,url: {action: "resume_update"},id: "resume_form", :html =>{ :multipart => true}, method: :post, remote: true do |t| %>
      <label class="btn btn-primary btn-file btn-lg" id="resume_button">
        + Resume
        <%= t.input :resume, style: "display:none", label: false%>
        <%= t.hidden_field :id, value: @applicant.id %>
      <label>
    <% end %>
```

custom controller module

```
def resume_update
  applicant = Applicant.find(params.require(:applicant).permit(:id, :resume)[:id])
  applicant.resume = params.require(:applicant).permit(:resume, :id)[:resume]
  if applicant.save
    respond_to do |format|
      format.js
    end
  end
end
```

routes lines that handle the ajax request

```
  resources :applicants do
    member do
      post :refer
    end
    collection do
      post :resume_update
    end
  end
```

I would like to know how to create a client side handler for the submit command with coffeescript.